# Experience Manager (XPM) without CDA in client application

Tags: content-delivery, experience-manager

Part I:
Is it possible to use Experience Manager (specifically to make *existing content modifications) from an application that does not use content delivery (CDA) binaries. For example, from static html files that are published to the file system?

SDL docs only reference implementation from .NET and Java clients (using content delivery binaries); however, given that XPM appears to work based on markup comments, javascript, and OData webservice, it seems it should be technically feasible. e.g. output the html comments from TBB or manually and reference SiteEdit Javascript manually.

Part II:
If this is technically feasible, would it also be possible to use XPM from a SPA app (e.g. AngularJS) that uses a client-side library to fetch content via OData webservice from client side?

Part III:
If technically feasible, are there any license implications regarding the use of XPM from an application that does not leverage content delivery license?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

XPM itself does not require any Content Delivery DLLs, it works based on the bootstrap Javascript which injects HTML on your staging site. The content is edited directly in the CM through the XPM editor on the CM.

Only for Session Preview you will need to enable the Ambient Data Framework. And if you publish pages (aspx files) to disk in a web application you will need the PreviewContentModule as well.

So to backup my answer to #1, take a look at how [DD4T](http://dd4t.org/) and [DXA](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/852) implement XPM, they indeed write out the XPM markup themselves in their views and add the bootstrap script.

To answer #2, read the following blogposts http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/client-side-templating-with-json-odata-and-angular and http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/edit-ajax-loaded-content-with-experience-manager-really

As for #3, there are no license restrictions of you using XPM on your site, if your content is published from SDL Tridion, you can use XPM to edit that in context (regardless of how you get that content in your website).